# PostGIS ST_RECLASS using Lookup Table not working properly

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, postgis-raster

[Link to question/answer similar to what I am trying to do](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/298080/129448)

I am trying to run ST_RECLASS on a raster to retain certain pixel values while setting others to NoData(0).  I have a function that creates a lookup table and then I embed the lookup table within the UPDATE query using ST_RECLASS to try to reassign the output pixel valuese.

The raster, before relcass attempt, has these values: (BEC_ZONE_CLIP_RASTER_RASTER)

[image: Raster Values]

My lookup table contains the following values: (ZZ_TMP_LOOKUP)

[image]

When I execute the following line of code:

```
UPDATE BEC_ZONE_CLIP_RASTER_RASTER SET rast = ST_Reclass(rast, ROW(1, (SELECT string_agg(concat('[', val, ']:', out_val), ',')  FROM zz_tmp_lookup), '4BUI', 0)::reclassarg);
```

I end up with the pixels that represent 17 and 21 values reclassed, but they are set to value 15.  Can somebody help me to understand why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Note: I have tried creating the lookup table to integers to match the pixel type of the raster and the values within both.  Makes no difference.

Comment: [Also posted here at this similar issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127300/postgis-replace-pixel-value-by-lookup-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was stuck in a big rut here and clearly could not see the obvious.  I had '4BUI' as the output Pixel Type.  That type can only handle 16 values, which, when you include NoData 0 leaves 15 as the max value available.  Changed to '32BUI' and all is well

```
UPDATE BEC_ZONE_CLIP_RASTER_RASTER SET rast = ST_Reclass(rast, ROW(1, (SELECT string_agg(concat('[', val,'-', val, ']:', out_val::INTEGER), ',')  FROM (SELECT VAL, OUT_VAL from zz_tmp_lookup where out_val <> 0 order by val asc) foo), '32BUI', 0)::reclassarg);
```